# Logged In user Id is displaying as null in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core Web API I have this code as shown below:

```
using System.Security.Claims;

public class MemberService: IMemberService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MemberService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<MemberModel> Post(MemberCreateDto memberCreateDto)
    {
        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var member = mapper.FromMemberCreateDtoToMember(memberCreateDto);
        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));

        try
        {
            await _unitOfWork.MemberRepository.Insert(member);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return member;
    }
}
```

I used IdentityDbContext. There I have ApplicationUser.

I am trying to retrieve the logged in user id, and then save it into the Member table (userId).

But from my code above **userId**  returns null

Even when I changed it from:

```
var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

into

```
var principal = new ClaimPrincipal();
var userId principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

It still returns null.

**I am not doing it from the controller.***

How do I resolve this?

Comment: 1. your first example - does the claim actually exist and 2. your 2nd example will be an empty `Principal`

Comment: i'd also avoid coupling your `MemberService` to the http context.

Comment: @DanielA.White - How do you mean if the claim exists

Comment: how is your authentication configured?

Comment: Do you have a claim of type `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`? Have you checked whether the user is logged in at the point the service gets called? Have you checked which claims the user has?

Comment: Also, this level of coupling is unnecessary and mostly kills the possibility of unit testing `MemberService`. I'd really remove the `IHttpContextAccessor` for this type of logic. Also, please **never** do `throw new Exception(e.Message);`, look up on StackOverflow the number of problems that single lines has.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - what's the best approach? And How do I get the Id of the logged in user?